# Trying to run cmake on Chipmunk errors occuring how to fix cmake files?

Tags: cmake, chipmunk

SO basically i am trying to build Chipmunk physics library on linux mint, and it has a cmake file obviously, which i tried to run and it did not complete due to some error , the output was

```
cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_policy):
  Policy "CMP0042" is not known to this version of CMake.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Configuring Chipmunk2D version 7.0.1
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dev/Downloads/Chipmunk2D-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

okay i found the error from the CMakeError output file

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
```

any idea how i can fix the cmake files to work?

Comment: one thing I see is the error messages indicate it is looking for `/usr/bin/cc` rather than `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: cc does exist in bin, and you can run it just like gcc

Comment: the /usr/bin/cc is just a link to /etc/alternatives/cc which is just another link to /usr/bin/gcc.    it seems that configuration operation has some problems with following the multiple links (I'm on Linux, not windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CMake version is too old. CMP0042 was introduced in CMake 2.8.12.

You can try to remove the line in CMakeLists.txt:3, it should be `make_policy(CMP0042)`. But no guarantee that the other parts will work as expected.

Comment: i installed the latest version of Cmake and it did the job, thanks